# Image is shown as blurred in ImageView while using mipmap resource directory

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-imageview, android-drawable

While loading image in **ImageView** for Android Studio using **android:src="@mipmap/stunner** my image is getting **blurred out**, What to do?? Please help...

My code is as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@mipmap/stunner"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
```

[image: The screenshot of my Android Studio layout]

[image: The image I want to load]

Comment: please put stunner image in drawable folder and use like android:background="@drawable/stunner" and check

Comment: What if you do this? `android:background="@mipmap/stunner"`

Comment: its good practice to use mipmap for launcher icons and your other images in the drawable

Comment: @prasad_21 you need `stunner` image of multiple densities and add those in the drawable folder with respective densities

Comment: Thanks guys, android:src="@drawable/stunner" solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use it as a drawable rather than using it as a mipmap. Mipmap is used for app icons but not for drawables

Here is the code and output with drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/archive_task_open_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]